# .htaccess RewriteRule issue here

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, so I am using this code in a .htaccess file.  This is the only code in there, but it doesn't seem to work at all and I know I have mod_rewrite installed and enabled.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news\.js news.php [NC]
```

have also tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule news.js news.php [NC]
```

Ok, so, I am using news.php to output a JS Script that I am linking to elsewhere.  So I want all links to news.js (and all links with text after this), to point to news.php instead.  And so news.php outputs the Javascript for this, but is a PHP file...

Am I setting up the PHP file correctly?

```
<?php

// If there is a php error for any reason...hide it!
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');

// Set the header-type.
header('Content-type: application/x-javascript');

// And it calls some functions in here

?>
```

The problem is that it isn't working.  Can someone please help me?  Is my .htaccess file not set up properly?

Thanks for any help you can offer me.

Comment: *it isn't working* needs more explanation. What happens when you open *news.js* in the browser? Do you get a 404 error?

Comment: No error, I get nothing.  The javascript code works, so I don't understand why it isn't working.  If I link the call to the news.php file instead, it works perfect, but linking to news.js doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Solo: I mean does Apache complain that it cannot find the file when you enter the `http://url/to/news.js` in browser address bar or does it send the expected javascript content?

Comment: You try it.  The URL is this:  http://news.dream-portal.net/news.js and it displays the content as a script file just fine, but something is a miss somewhere because it doesn't work when I use it within a file for some reason.

Comment: @solo: everything looks ok, there is probably nothing wrong in Apache configuration or your code. One thing: in the page where you include news.js or news.php, do you also include other javascript files? Such as the one that defines setDPNews/setDPVersion functions?

Comment: No, `setDPNews()` and `setDPVersion()` functions are echo'd before news.php/news.js is even loaded.  These functions are hard-coded into the file that calls news.js.  news.js is the shorter url, there is much more text after news.js.  But like I said, it works if I change it to news.php (with the php extension), but doesn't work when it is news.js (with the js extension).  Any more ideas?

Comment: news.js is being loaded at the very last line within the `<body>` tag of the page, does that matter you think?

Comment: correction, `setDPNews()` and `setDPVersion()` are defined within the header, so within the `<head>` tag of the page.

Comment: @solo: all sounds OK. Now *I* am confused what could be wrong.

Comment: Well, if you go here:  http://news.dream-portal.net/news.js?v=1.1+Beta+1;smf_version=SMF+2.0+RC5 you see it being echo'd out in PHP format instead of JS format.  What could be causing this?  Is it because of the `+` signs in the URL?

Comment: Ok, don't know how it got fixed, but it is working now as it should.  Thanks for your help just the same! :)

Answer (score 0):

do you have AllowOverride enabled for your .htaccess to work? http://www.blackbeagle.com/web-hosting/apache-mod_rewrite-and-allowoverride/

Comment: So if I use `Options +FollowSymlinks` this doesn't work either.